# Testing Approaches

Tags: testing, black-box, white-box

I'm currently writing my dissertation and am investigating software quality and testing.

I am finding it very difficult to differentiate between the following terms and wondered if anyone can help me in doing so.

**(Dynamic and Static Testing) and (Validation and Verification Testing)**

I'm currently of the understanding that Dynamic Testing and Validation Testing are the same thing, as are Static Testing and Verification Testing. I think that dynamic testing referes to testing the performance and behaviour of a system, whilst static testing looks at checks such as control flow ,data flow ,coding standards and code metrics.

Am I on the right lines with this? (I believe so)

**Black-Box and White-Box Testing**

My biggest issue is understanding where these two come in. From some sources, I begin to believe that these are the same as dynamic and static testing. But others make me believe these are just categories of testing techniques such as boundary analysis and partition testing.

Any help in this area would be great !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, there all four terms are different.

**Dynamic Testing:** Testing that involves the execution of the software of a component or
system.

When you are talking about **Dynamic Testing**, your source code are in **executing stage**. You are trying to find bug by inputting values in system.

**Static Testing:** Testing of a software development artifact, e.g., requirements, design or code, without execution of these artifacts, e.g., reviews or static analysis. In simple words,

In **static testing** your source code is **not in executing stage**, you are targeting the documentation part to finding bugs.

**Validation:** Confirmation by examination and through provision of objective evidence that the requirements for a specific intended use or application have been fulfilled.

**Verification:** Confirmation by examination and through provision of objective evidence that specified requirements have been fulfilled.

*See below image which explain diffrance between **Validation & Varification**.*
[image]

**black box testing:** Testing, either functional or non-functional, without reference to the internal structure of the component or system.

**white-box testing:** Testing based on an analysis of the internal structure of the component or system.

Answer (score 0):

Black Box: For this approach you don't need to have any programming skills.
Black Box Testing is a software testing method in which the internal structure/ design/ implementation of the item being tested is NOT known to the tester

White Box: In this approach you must have programming skills. 
White Box Testing is a software testing method in which the internal structure/ design/ implementation of the item being tested is known to the tester.